# I want to use GoLang's regular expression to perform an ambiguous search for values enclosed in the `*` string

Tags: regex, go

I'm not good at regular expressions.
I want to use fuzzy search to get the value of a key enclosed with * in text.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    text := "*company*  example company!!\n*tel*  09000009999\n*"
    
    regex := fmt.Sprintf(`(?m)\*%s\*\s\s(.+)$`, "company")
    rep := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
    result := rep.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
    if result != nil {
        log.Print(result[0][1])
    } else {
        log.Print("empty")
    }
}
```

Output results

```
example company!!
```

Change the text variable.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    text := "*company_name*  example company!!\n*tel*  09000009999\n*"
    
    regex := fmt.Sprintf(`(?m)\*%s\*\s\s(.+)$`, "company")
    rep := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
    result := rep.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
    if result != nil {
        log.Print(result[0][1])
    } else {
        log.Print("empty")
    }
}
```

Output results

```
empty
```

How do I get `company` in an ambiguous search?
I want to search for something like "like 'company%'" like in the SQL like clause.

Comment: I didn't understand : you insert "company" and your text have "company_name". Do you forget to replace the the variable or you want something like the like clause in sql "like 'company%'" ? 

If you want to match all alphabetical characters after company until * you can use : 
(?m)\*%s\w+?\*\s\s(.+)$ 

Don't forget the ? after + : it switch the + comportment from greedy to lazy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Your current title says nothing that is meaningful in any way. It's no more specific than a post that says *About cars in America* - it means nothing. The tags you added already say that the post is about *regex in go*, so none of the words in your title convey any information.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the title and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it's done.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    text := "*1company_name1234*  example company!!\n*tel*  09000009999\n*"
    
    regex := fmt.Sprintf(`(?m)\*.*%s.*\*\s\s(.+)$`, "company")
    rep := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
    result := rep.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
    if result != nil {
        log.Print(result[0][1])
    } else {
        log.Print("empty")
    }
}
```